# Python requests.get() throwing SSLError with verify=False

Tags: python, python-requests

I am putting together a simple interface for ThePirateBay (using a mirror) and requests.get() is returning an SSLError - I am specifying verify=False as other posts have recommended with no luck. I'm running Python 2.7.10 on MacOS Sierra.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.fastbay.net"
categories = {'anime': 1,
        'software': 2,
        'games': 3,
        'adult': 4,
        'movies': 5,
        'music': 6,
        'other': 7,
        'series': 8,
        'books': 9}
sort = ['created_at', 'size', 'seeders', 'leechers']


class PirateBayAPI(object):


_instance = None

def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if not cls._instance:
        cls._instance = super(PirateBayAPI, cls).__new__(
            cls, *args, **kwargs)
    return cls._instance

def search(self, term, category='all', sort_criteria=None, asc=False):
    global url, categories, sort
    term = term.replace(' ','%20')
    resource = "%s/search/%s" % (url, term)

    req = requests.get(resource, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content)
    res = []

    for torrent in soup.findAll('tr'):
        try:
            date = torrent.find('td', attrs={'class': 'date-row'}).text
            size = torrent.find('td', attrs={'class': 'size-row'}).text
            seeders = torrent.find('td', attrs={'class': 'seeders-row'}).text
            leechers = torrent.find('td', attrs={'class': 'leechers-row'}).text
            magnet_link = torrent.find('a', attrs={'title': 'MAGNET LINK'})['href']
            link = "%s%s" % (url, torrent.findAll('a')[1]['href'])
            name = torrent.find('span').text
            t = {'date': date, 'size': size, 'seeders': int(seeders), 'leechers': int(leechers), 'magnet_link': magnet_link, 'name': name, 'link': link}
            res.append(t)
        except:
            pass
    return res
```

Please excuse the Class indentation... :)

The error returned is:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.fastbay.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search/walking%20dead (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)'),))
```

Thanks!

Comment: `verify=False` tells requests not to care if the certificate the server presents is invalid. Your error says that requests can't even begin communicating with the server properly, so your error is much lower-level. What Python installation are you using?

Comment: I remember having this issue on one of my Linux machines awhile ago and it was related to OpenSSL. If I remember right, update of pyOpenSSL fixed the issue.